# Transparent box around table CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make a transparent box behind a table, that I can use as a background for it, but it appears left to right side of my page and not only behind the table. Any ideas how I can fix that?

Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HEAD>
<LINK href="Menu/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<LINK href="Pictures/Background.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<LINK href="Style/Boxes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<nav class="nav">
<ul>
<li class="current"><a href="#"><b>MENU</b></a></li>
<li><a href="Index.html">BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MUSIC</a></li>
<li><a href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
<li><a href="#">QUOTES & THOUGHTS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
</ul>
</nav><br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="BlueBox">
<TABLE border="0" align="center" width="60%">
<TR>
<TD ROWSPAN="2" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD valign="bottom" align="center"><b><i><FONT SIZE="6" COLOR="FFFFFF">What can I say about myself...</FONT></i></b></TD>
<TD ROWSPAN="2" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
<TD ROWSPAN="2"><IMG SRC="Pictures/Me.JPG" height="400"></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD valign="middle" align="left" >
TEXT
 </TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is the CSS for the box:

```
.BlueBox{
position:fixed;
background-color:rgba(0,157,255,0.7);
padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Just simply remove  **position:fixed;**  from your css.

.BlueBox{
position:fixed;
background-color:rgba(0,157,255,0.7);
padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is just a block element (table) inside another block element (div.bluebox)... nothing that should prevent your example from rendering as you expect it.

For debugging the design, I would recommend you to remove all other css files and the rowspans in the table to get a minimal example.